# onItemClick not called in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

Here is my **Fragment1.kt** overall code

```
class Fragment1 : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: Fragment1Binding
    private lateinit var list : ArrayList<TasksItem>
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var manager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    private lateinit var myAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false)

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.app_list)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        list = arrayListOf()
        manager = LinearLayoutManager(this.requireContext())

        GroomedKidzApi.retrofitService.getTasksProgress().enqueue(object :
            Callback<List<TasksItem>?> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<TasksItem>?>,
                response: Response<List<TasksItem>?>
            ) {
                val responseBody = response.body()

                if (responseBody != null) {
                    recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.app_list).apply {
                        myAdapter = TaskAdapter(response.body()!!)
                        layoutManager = manager
                        adapter = myAdapter
                        Log.e("TAG", "response 33: "+ (response.body()) )
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<TasksItem>?>, t: Throwable) {

            }
        })


        var adapter = TaskAdapter(list)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : TaskAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
                    val intent = Intent(activity,ViewTaskActivity::class.java).apply{
                        putExtra("taskname", list[position].taskName)
                        putExtra("desc", list[position].taskDesc)
                        putExtra("category", list[position].category)
                        putExtra("duedate", list[position].dueDate)
                        putExtra("assignee", list[position].assignee)
                        putExtra("point", list[position].pointEarned)
                        Log.d("Fragment1", "onViewCreated executed")
                }
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the **TaskAdapter** overall code

```
class TaskAdapter(val list: List<TasksItem> ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var listener2: OnItemClickListener? = null

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener){
        listener2 = listener
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item,
            parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView,listener2)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val currentitem = list[position]

        holder.TaskName.text = currentitem.taskName
        holder.Date.text = currentitem.dueDate
        holder.Assignee.text = currentitem.assignee
        holder.Status.text = currentitem.taskStatus

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }


    class MyViewHolder(itemView : View, listener: OnItemClickListener?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val TaskName : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTaskname)
        val Assignee : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAssignee)
        val Date : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate)
        val Status : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                listener?.onItemClick(adapterPosition)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The logcat for `Log.d("Fragment1", "onViewCreated executed")` inside the `onItemClick` is not being called. However, others functions can be called successfully.

Any reason why is the `onItemClick` is not being called? All functions works fine even the API.

Notes: Adapter is fine, `setOnClickListener` able to get the position as well

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be an issue with the setOnClickListener implementation in your TaskAdapter.

```
class TaskAdapter(val list: List<TasksItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var listener: OnItemClickListener? = null

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener) {
        this.listener = listener
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView, listener)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentitem = list[position]
        holder.TaskName.text = currentitem.taskName
        holder.Date.text = currentitem.dueDate
        holder.Assignee.text = currentitem.assignee
        holder.Status.text = currentitem.taskStatus
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View, listener: OnItemClickListener?) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val TaskName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTaskname)
        val Assignee: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAssignee)
        val Date: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate)
        val Status: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                listener?.onItemClick(adapterPosition)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Ensure that you are calling setOnItemClickListener on your adapter instance in the Fragment1 class:

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : TaskAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
        val intent = Intent(activity, ViewTaskActivity::class.java).apply {
            // Put extras
        }
        startActivity(intent)
    }
})
```

Comment: is inside this functions `override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you must call `setOnClickListener` in `onBindViewHolder`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    ...
    holder.ItemView.setOnClickListener{
        listener2?.onItemClick(position)
    }
}

class MyViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val ItemView : View = itemView
    ...
}
```

and please note that `recyclerView.adapter` is re-assigned to `myAdapter` that has no click listener

```
myAdapter = TaskAdapter(response.body()!!)
layoutManager = manager
adapter = myAdapter
```

You can refer this way:

```
    if (responseBody != null) {
        myAdapter.updateList(response.body()!!)
    }
            
myAdapter = TaskAdapter(list)
recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter
myAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(...)
```

Comment: Tried but `adapter` file works fine, but not my `fragment`

Comment: You need to extend the interface of OnItemClickListener to your fragment

Comment: @Cyd i cant put the inside my API class as it will affect my data not showing in the fragment

Comment: Please note that `recyclerView.adapter` is re-assigned to `myAdapter = TaskAdapter(response.body()!!)` that has no click listener. Did you check this point?